# Port unreachable when VPN turned on

Tags: android, vpn

I have an Android application that opens a port for communication. The application acts as a server.

Android 9:

- When a VPN is switched on and my application is running my application's open port is still reachable over the local IP address.
- `nmap` shows my application's port as open over the local network IP address

Android 10:

- When a VPN is switched on and my application is running the open port is no longer reachable over the local IP address. The port is still opened but no requests make it to my application. `tcpdump` shows no response from the server whatsoever over the local IP address. My application **is** still reachable over the VPN's IP address.
- `nmap` shows my application's port as filtered over the local network IP address

When a VPN is switched on, for both Android 9 and Android 10, both the local network IP as well as the VPN network IP addresses are assigned to the device. My clients to the server are trying to reach the device using the local IP address.

**Note**: I've had reports of multiple VPN applications that result in the same behavior. When a user updates their device from Android 9 -> Android 10 my application no longer works.

Are there any changes made in Android 10 that would change this behavior? Does my application need to request any additional permissions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the Android build-in IPSEC based VPN or a third part VPN app?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for coming back to me.

My testing is with a third party VPN applicaiton

Comment: Well then you should may be better ask the developer of the third party VPN app and edit your question and exactly name the used VPN app.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll update my question. It's not just this one single VPN application but I have heard that my application is affected by numerous VPN applications leading me to think that it's a change in Android as opposed to a change in individual VPN applications.

Comment: Is there a VPN client with which it works successfully in Android 10 ?

Comment: @HarshVerma Not that I have found yet

Comment: Maybe there are some new VPN settings available in new Android? Found something called `Block Non-VPN connections`  https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/9213914?hl=en

Comment: @HarshVerma I've already investigated that route thanks. That switch is currently off in my tests and still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the **allowed list** functionality of creating a VPN connection on Android 9 does not work as intended.

My testing

Android 9:

- Set up a VPN connection using [OpenConnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.digitalsoftwaresolutions.openconnect)
- Make sure my app is in the App Filter
- Start my application
- Test connection to my application from another device on the same local network
- My application works but it shouldn't (it's not in the allowed list via the App Filter of OpenConnect)

Android 10:

- Set up a VPN connection using [OpenConnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.digitalsoftwaresolutions.openconnect)
- Make sure my app is in the App Filter
- Start my application
- Test connection to my application from another device on the same local network
- My application port is filtered and therefore I cannot connect to my application
- Remove my application from the App Filter
- My application works as expected

My understanding is that the way my application works on Android 10 is correct as per the documentation however my application working on Android 9 without having to update the **allowed list** or **disallowed list** of the VPN application is incorrect. This led to me trying to figure out whether this was permissions based etc. as I expected my application to work the same way on Android 10 as it did on Android 9.